# Call function FindNextFile throw access violation exception

Tags: c, winapi, access-violation, unhandled-exception

I write a c program using Win32 API [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find files

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<tchar.h>
#include<windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    HANDLE hNextFile;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA findFileData;
    LPCTSTR fileName = argv[1]; //input argument "C:\test\file*.txt"

    hNextFile = FindFirstFile(fileName, &findFileData);

    while(hNextFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("long name: %s\t8dot3 name: %s\n", findFileData.cFileName, findFileData.cAlternateFileName);
        hNextFile = FindNextFile(fileName, &findFileData); //Unhandled exception here!
    }
    printf("%s", GetLastError());
    return 0;
}
```

When call FindNextFile firstly, it throw exception.
Exception info:

> Unhandled exception at 0x77178dc9 in findfile.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation writing location 0x005c0080.

Could you give me some suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

---

I have modified my code like this, it works fine. Thanks for Pierre's explain.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<tchar.h>
#include<windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    HANDLE hNextFind;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA findFileData;
    LPCTSTR fileName = argv[1];
    BOOL result = TRUE;

    if((hNextFind = FindFirstFile(fileName, &findFileData)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return 1;

    while(result)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("long name: %s\t8dot3 name: %s\n"), findFileData.cFileName, findFileData.cAlternateFileName);
        result = FindNextFile(hNextFind, &findFileData);
    }
    FindClose(hNextFind);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile for me... The prototype for FindNextFile is : `BOOL FindNextFile( HANDLE, LPWIN32_FIND_DATA);` ...

Comment: I find a sample using function FindFirstFile, FindNextFile and FindClose in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365200(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Yes, it shows the same thing about the use of `FindNextFile` the pass an `HANDLE` to it and get the `BOOL` returned by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many errors in your code.

- First, you do not use FindNextFile correctly, the prototype :

  ```
  BOOL WINAPI FindNextFile(
    _In_   HANDLE hFindFile,
    _Out_  LPWIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData
  );
  ```
- After, you do not use `GetLastError()` correctly, who fire an Exception. `GetLastError` return a `DWORD`, you can print it as a string. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx)

Here is an example of what your code should look like :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<tchar.h>
#include<windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    HANDLE hNextFile;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA findFileData;
    LPCTSTR fileName = argv[1]; //input argument "C:\test\file*.txt"

    hNextFile = FindFirstFile(fileName, &findFileData);
    BOOL res = TRUE;
  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    while(hNextFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE && res)
    //                                      ^^^^^^
    {
        printf("long name: %s\t8dot3 name: %s\n", findFileData.cFileName, findFileData.cAlternateFileName);
        res = FindNextFile(hNextFile, &findFileData); //Unhandled exception here!
      //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
    printf("%d", GetLastError());
    //      ^^  // You can also use FormatMessage as it is said in the documentation
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not checking the value of `res` anywhere.

Comment: In the `while`. I just added it.

Answer (score 0):

`FindNextFile` returns TRUE or FALSE, it doesn't return a `HANDLE`. The original handle you got from `FindFirstFile` remains valid until you pass it to `FindClose`.

```
hNextFile = FindFirstFile(fileName, &findFileData);
if(hNextFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    do
    {
        printf("long name: %s\t8dot3 name: %s\n", findFileData.cFileName, findFileData.cAlternateFileName);
    } while (FindNextFile(fileName, &findFileData));
    FindClose(hNextFile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your code.

Your original code reads:

> ```
> hNextFile = FindNextFile(fileName, &findFileData);
> ```

But if you check the [prototype of `FindNextFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you will find:

> ```
> BOOL WINAPI FindNextFile(
>   _In_   HANDLE hFindFile,
>   _Out_  LPWIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData
> );
> ```

So, the function returns a `BOOL` and the first parameter is a `HANDLE`, which is not what you have in your code.

Moreover, you have:

> ```
> printf("long name: %s\t8dot3 name: %s\n", findFileData.cFileName,
>        findFileData.cAlternateFileName);
> ```

But this is not coherent with the `TCHAR` model that you use in other parts of your code.
To be coherent, you should use `_tprintf()` instead of `printf()`, and decorate strings using `_T("...")` or `TEXT("...")`:

```
// Use _tprintf() and _T("...") for coherence with TCHAR model
_tprintf(_T("long name: %s\t8dot3 name: %s\n"), 
         findFileData.cFileName, findFileData.cAlternateFileName);
```

Moreover, you have:

> ```
> printf("%s", GetLastError());
> ```

`GetLastError()` returns a `DWORD`, which is an unsigned 32-bit integer.
But in the `printf()` format string you used `%s`, which is the placeholder for a raw C string.
Instead, you may want to use the `%u` format specifier (and use `_tprintf()` for coherence with the `TCHAR` model):

```
_tprintf(_T("Last error code: %u\n"), GetLastError());
```

Note that MSDN has an example on [**Listing the Files in a Directory**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).